# the definition of a maximally balanced tree

Tags: algorithm, tree

I am writing a method that builds a balanced binary search tree out of an already sorted `LinkedList` and I need to figure out whether the resulting tree is maximally balanced or not.

I am still a little confused with the definition on a *maximally balanced tree*. In the [website](http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61bl/su15/materials/lab/lab18/lab18.html) I am self-studying, it only says it was mentioned in the lecture but since I wasn't there, I had tried to find the definition else where but I couldn't find a clear definition.

So I'd like to ask find here

1. What is the definition, if exists, of a maximally balanced tree? What are the components that don't make a maximally balanced tree?
2. And how is that different from normal **balanced tree** that I know?

Comment: It's a problem. Either the definition for "maximally balanced tree" is easily searchable on the internet, in which case you should provide a link, or it is not, in which case how can people know to what you refer?

Comment: Why do you need to know whether the tree is maximally balanced?  Is this a homework problem?  If so, then your professor may have his/her own definition.  I suggest asking at office hours.

Comment: @AmiTavory I tried to search for the definition but it was not easily searchable for me. Like I mentioned above, I try to write a method that builds a balanced binary search tree from the sorted linked list and I want to find the succinct definition on the term "maximally balanced" and the differences between the "maximally balanced" and "balanced".

Comment: @KenClubok well.. this is not homework question. I am studying data structure of my own and it was like a small discussion question but I wasn't sure with the term "maximally balanced" and how is that different from regular "balanced" tree. I thought this has an official definition that I couldn't find

Comment: In this case, in what context did you come across the term?

Comment: @KenClubok Like I mentioned, I am writing a method that changes sorted linkedlist to balanced search tree and I want to figure out if that's maximally balanced tree. Now I am more confused whether the term "maximally balanced" even exists. I just wondered if it's different from the regular  "balanced tree" that I know..

Comment: The counterexamples of "Almost balanced" trees on that site are instructive.  They imply that "Maximally" balanced trees are ones in which such compromises are not made in the balancing.

Comment: @KenClubok Thanks for the comment. :) I am thinking that maximally balanced tree is not very different from regular balanced tree. I will try to compare it with almost balanced tree more.

Comment: I thankfully found the answer. The maximally balanced tree has all available positions for nodes filled, except for possibly the last row, which must be filled left-to-right. So it's almost like a balanced binary tree that is filled left-to-right. And it's useful when we implement Binary min/max heaps.

Answer (score 1):

Simply looking at the name **maximally balanced** means that **is not possible to balance it better**.

In any tree maximally balanced is a tree where difference of most depth of a node without both children and any other node without both children is at most 1.

Example of tree with 4 elements:

```
Maximally Balanced     Not maximally Balanced
   2                           1
1     3                             2
         4                              3
                                             4
```

Because in tree maximally balanced you have:

```
Maximally balanced                 Not maximally balanced
Node depth                         Node depth
1    2                             1   1
3    2                             2   2
4    3                             3   3         
                                   4   4
```

Comment: I found the answer I had been looking for. The maximally balanced tree has all available positions for nodes filled, except for possibly the last row, which must be filled left-to-right. So it's almost like a balanced binary tree that is filled left-to-right. Thanks for your response too!